# How to print cck field (multiple checkboxes) values in node?

Tags: drupal, checkbox

I'm using CCK fields in my drupal node type. There's a field called field_signs, which is type Text / Checkboxes and it contains some values. What i want is to print those values in node template. But i don't know how to do this. I tried this:

```
<?php
echo $node->field_signs[0]['value'];
?>
```

But this prints ONLY the first checked value from all checked values.

Any idea?

Thanks

// EDIT // Maybe i found a solution.

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while (!$end) {
  if(array_key_exists($i, $node->field_test)) {
  echo $node->field_test[$i]['value'];
  $i++;
  } else {
  $end = TRUE;
  }
}
?>
```

If you have better solution, feel free to share with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Go to http://YOUR_DRUPAL_HOST/admin/content/node-type/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/template
2. Click *Body*
3. Click *Body Variables*

OR

1. Administer
2. Content Types
3. Edit
4. Template
5. Body
6. Body Variables

Now you can see all your variables and how to print them.

Comment: i haven't this option in my drupal installation :/

Comment: Enable Content Templates module from CCK.

Comment: No problem. If your problem is solved you can close this by accepting the answer :)